how to stop rectangle on edge of canvas while moving it by pressing 'a' or 'd' key
So I was trying to create a brick break game on canvas in python, I made a rectangular bar so the ball will collide on it and bounce back, well the problem is very simple and I couldn't find any
solution on the internet, it is : my rectangle on pressing 'a' or 'd' key it moves to left
and right respectively but when they come to edge I have written code which should have stopped
it to move any further but my rectangle still moves while pressing 'a' or 'd' out of the edge of canvas, so please look into my code and help me out there and please give me a method
which will help me to learn collide concept in canvas.
code --
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
import time

score = 0

def left(event):

    if paddle_coordinates[0] <= 0 or paddle_coordinates[2] >= 750:  # this is not working
        canvas.move(paddle, 0,0)
    else:
        canvas.move(paddle, -10,0)

def right(event):

    if paddle_coordinates[0] <= 0 or paddle_coordinates[2] >= 750:  # and this one also
        canvas.move(paddle, 0, 0)
    else:
        canvas.move(paddle, 10,0)

window = tk.Tk()
window.title('Game')
window.geometry('800x600+265+50')

score_label = Label(window, font = ('consolas',40), text = 'Score : {}'.format(score))
score_label.pack(side = 'top')

canvas = Canvas(window, width = 750, height = 550, bg = 'black')
canvas.pack(padx = 25, pady = 25)

paddle = canvas.create_rectangle(10,400,110,405, fill = 'white')
window.bind('<a>',left)
window.bind('<d>',right)
paddle_coordinates = canvas.coords(paddle)

window.mainloop()


The variable paddle_coordinates never changes.  A few debug print statements would have shown you that.  You need to fetch the actual X coordinate from the live paddle.

You need to check the live coordinates, not the copy you saved at startup:
def left(event):
    if canvas.coords(paddle)[0] > 0:
        canvas.move(paddle, -10,0)

def right(event):
    if canvas.coords(paddle)[2] <= 750:
        canvas.move(paddle, 10,0)


I think the checking condition should be canvas.coords(paddle)[2] < 750 instead inside right().

thank you it works, it was a very silly mistake I will pay more attention from now on
